# Can a struct have lazy properties [instantiation] in Swift?

Tags: swift, struct, lazy-initialization

Can a struct have lazy properties [instantiation] in Swift?

I cannot find any documentation saying yes or no.  Everything only uses classes as examples.

If one can, can an example be found anywhere?

Thanks

Stan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes a struct can have a lazy property.  Consider this example:

```
class Stuff {
    var stuff: Int

    init(value: Int) {
        print("Stuff created with value \(value)")
        stuff = value
    }
}

struct HasLazy {
    lazy var object = Stuff(value: 1)
    var object2 = Stuff(value: 2)
}

func testIt() {
    print("in testIt")

    var haslazy = HasLazy()

    print("done")
    haslazy.object.stuff = 17
    print("\(haslazy.object.stuff)")
    print("final")
}

testIt()
```

Output:

> ```
> in testIt
> Stuff created with value 2
> done
> Stuff created with value 1
> 17
> final
> ```

Notice that the property marked `lazy` is not initialized until after `"done"` prints when the property is first accessed.

See it in action [here](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/57e1d1af87c13408d558f15e), and then try it without the `lazy` keyword.

Comment: OK Perfect just what i was looking for.  Thanks!